# USB authentication and Encryption on Windows Environment

Tags: active-directory, encryption, disk-encryption

My boss ask me that he want to secure USB thumb drive usage on our company. He want the USB thumb drive data **un-encrypted** when some one authenticate to our Active Directory (AD) server whether locally or by VPN and will be **encrypted** if not authenticated with our AD server example brought the USB thumb drive outside of company. Additionally the USB will be denied if not registered previously in software that capable of doing such thing.

I am aware of bitlocker solution, but that not what we want. If you know any solution available please let me know.

Sorry for my bad English - thank you in advance.

Comment: `I am aware of bitlocker solution, but that not what we want` - May I ask why not?

Comment: Because my boss seem want the encryption done on fly. Not manually, in bitlocker we must encrypt the thumb drive first and I can not see the bit locker could prevent some plug the thumb drive and copy data as he want if we not restrict thumb drive access by other mean such as antivirus protection but our antivirus do not have such kind of ability.

Comment: Take a look at Sophos Central. It has encryption, endpoint protection, data loss prevention, etc., etc. - https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/sophos-central.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much joeqwerty, I will study it. We are currently using sophos antivirus and not have idea since I am still newly on my current company and newly exposed with Windows System Administration since my background is networking guy.